Is there a way to compare stings in C using == operator?
I am just curious if somehow is it possible to reliably compare string using == operator.
I am well aware of strcmp function, but when I have to use it in my code often I would prefer using ==. Is there a way to somehow override the default behavior of '==' for some part of the code (to call strcmp in backgroud for example) and than use default behavior again?

No. You can't override operators in C and == is not comparing strings.

preprocessor tricks will not help you either

If you want to use the == operator to compare strings, then you need to write your own loop to compare the individual characters.

== is not defined on arrays in C, period, end of story (strings are stored in arrays).  If you really want to use == on string values, you would have to use a hash function on each string and compare the hashes -- hash(str1) == hash(str2).

Given s1 and s2 are pointers to null-terminated arrays of char, whenever s1 == s2 evaluates to 1, strcmp(s1, s2) will evaluate to 0.  This can occasionally be leveraged.  But the reverse is not true: strcmp(s1, s2) also evaluates to 0 in some cases where s1 == s2 evaluates to 0.

Is it an option to swtich to C++?

Re "Is there a way to compare stings in C using == operator?", Yes, by using it in a loop. int mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) { if ( s1 == s2 ) return 1; while (*s1 || *s2) { if (!(*(s1++) == *(s2++))) { return 0; } } return 1; } Best to use the existing strcmp rather than writing your own, though.
